# react native list without transparency

Tags: reactjs, react-native, view, position, scrollview

I got the following problem: I want to implement a location search bar with the google maps places api to generate results. Everything is working, but the listview(which's position prop is set to absolute) seems to be transparent. 
[image: imgur]

i already tried to set the containers opacity to 1 but that didnt helped. can someone tell me what i need to change to make to underlaying test-text not visible in the container?

my code: 
locationPicker:

```js
<View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                            <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeArea}>
                                <View style={styles.searchContainer}>
                                    <LocationSearchBar/>
                                </View>
                            </SafeAreaView>


                            <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                                <Text>test</Text>
                            </View>
                          

                        </View>
                        
searchContainer: {
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        minHeight: 60,
        paddingHorizontal: 16,
        paddingVertical: 10,
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.screen.alter
    }
```

locationSearchBar:

```js
<React.Fragment>

                        <TextInput
                            autoCorrect={false}
                            onChangeText={handleTextChange}
                            value={inputValue}
                            label={<Icon name={"search"} />}
                            placeholder={"Search location..."}
                        />
                        <ScrollView style={styles.autoCompleteResultList}>
                            {locationResults.map((el, i) => (
                                <AutoCompleteItem
                                    {...el}
                                    fetchDetails={fetchDetails}
                                    key={String(i)}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </ScrollView>

                    </React.Fragment>
       
AutoCompleteItem:
<View style={styles.autoCompleteItemContainer}>
                <RkText rkType={"primary2"}>{this.props.structured_formatting.main_text}</RkText>
                <RkText rkType={"primary1"}>{this.props.structured_formatting.secondary_text}</RkText>
            </View>



autoCompleteItemContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "red",
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
        paddingVertical: 5
    },
    autoCompleteResultList: {
        maxHeight: 200,
        position: "absolute",
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.screen.alter,
        width: "100%",
        top: 55
    }
```

cheers!

Comment: can you try putting the text in SafeAreaView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not a background-color or opacity problem.

It seems overlay problem of your position:absolute and default views

test is normal or default one so it has highest priority to come over any position:absolute views.

hence, test is above the results.

You'll need to change this position and make result above the test.

so do this by zIndex.

```
autoCompleteResultList: {
        maxHeight: 200,
        position: "absolute",
        backgroundColor: theme.colors.screen.alter,
        width: "100%",
        top: 55,
        zIndex:1 // highest number of zIndex in your current screen if you have other zIndex
    }
```

Comment: try zIndex in styles.safeArea